# Using LINQ to filter a list of items based on those items' presence in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I'm trying to learn LINQ by practice.  This seems like a situation where I should be able to use it, but I can't quite figure out if it's possible or if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Can I achieve what's in the brackets [] with a one-liner LINQ query given the use case below?

```
List<Command> list1, list2;

PopulateCommandLists(list1, list2);

foreach(Command cmd in list1)
{
    if ([cmd.Name is present as the Name in any of list2's Command objects])
    {
        //some code.
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, Lot's of good answers for this question. :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
if (list2.Any(l2c => l2c.Name == cmd.Name))
{ ... }
```

but you can add it to the `foreach` and avoid the `if` in your code:

```
foreach(Command cmd in list1.Where(l1c => list2.Any(l2c => l2c.Name == l1c.Name)))
{
    ... some code ...
}
```

If you control the `Command` class and can define equality in it (overriding Equals, etc), you can simply use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx):

```
foreach(var cmd in list1.Intersect(list2))
{ ... }
```

If you don't control `Command` or don't want to define equality in the class, you can still use `Intersect` with an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)

```
foreach(var cmd in list1.Intersect(list2, new CommandComparer()))
{ ... }

class CommandComparer : IEqualityComparer<Command>
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
if (list2.Any(item => item.Name == cmd.Name)) {
}
```

Here is the "anatomy" of the statement:

- `Any` applies its condition to each item of `list2`, and returns `true` if `true` has been returned for any item from the list
- The predicate inside `Any` tests for `item`'s name to be equal to that of `cmd`.

You can fold the `if` into LINQ as well:

```
foreach (var cmd in list1.Where(c => list2.Any(item => item.Name == c.Name))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In your last code, with the `Where` call, you cannot use the identifier `cmd` as a lambda variable because there's already a `foreach` variable with that name.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I was wrong! I just tested it. It looks like `cmd` is not in scope just after the `in` keyword, so your example worked before your edit. Sorry, I was too fast there.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's OK, the modified code is easier to read, as it leaves no ambiguity as to what each variable means, even if the reader (myself included) is not 100% certain about the scoping rules.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (list2.Any(x => x.Name == cmd.Name)) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
if(list2.Any(list2cmd=> list2cmd.Name == cmd.name))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the enumerable itself as:

```
var query = list1.Where(cmd => (list2.Any(item => item.Name == cmd.Name)));
```

Then just loop over query, which will contain every `Command` you want:

```
foreach( Command cmd in query)
{
    // Do something
}
```